# What is the method for counting how many bytes your program will be, reading from 32 bit x86 assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, machine-code, code-size

I am working on a simple stack smashing exercise. I need to write into my assembly a short jump of a specific offset. I need to calculate the offset by how many bytes the two instructions are separated by.

I have been searching google but I can't seem to get the right search terms.

I know, for example, that the `mov` opcode is 2 bytes. But how many bytes the whole instruction will be depends on your `src` and `dest` ... whether your are using immediate values or offsets, what the addressing mode is, etc.

I know there has to be a chart or something, somewhere, I can use to calculate this.

page 12 of Aleph One's Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit shows what I'm trying to do (count bytes from assembly code): http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf

Comment: If you just want to get the values, use an assembler. If you are interested in the method, consult the instruction set reference manual from intel.

Comment: It's not as simple as you think. The length of an instruction may vary. See there: [Instruction length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Instruction_length).

Comment: No, all the forms of `mov` have 1-byte opcodes, like `89` or `B8+reg`.  They all require a ModR/M byte (and thus optional SIB and/or disp8/disp32) and/or an immediate source (or an absolute address) so the length of the total instruction is at least 2 bytes for any `mov`.

Comment: Use a label, or 2 labels and take the difference, to get the assembler to calculate the `rel8` for you.  That's what labels are for!

Comment: If you want to learn about instruction lengths, read about how to optimize for code-size: 
 [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981).  And/or just get used to looking at instruction lengths in disassembly to get used to how instructions are encoded.  Or if you want to make something a specific length, see [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48046814) for making instructions *longer* intentionally.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments so far... unfortunately they are over my head. This is an intro to security class, and I'm only being made to write the attack in assembly to enforce how parameters go onto the stack for function calls, and how the kernel gets the information it needs from user space to execute system calls. I don't really know anything about programming in assembly, even though I can do a decent job of reading assembly.

Comment: So you need the answer for one *specific* case, and don't need a general rule.  Use an assembler to find that, like Brendan says in his answer.  Or better, use labels in the source for your shellcode so you can do `db label2 - label1` or `sub esp, l2 - l1` or whatever if you need it, or just `jmp label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to calculate the offset by how many bytes the two instructions are separated by.

The easy way is to slap your instructions into an online assembler (e.g. https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm ) and let it show you the bytes.

> I know there has to be a chart or something, somewhere, I can use to calculate this.

Intel's Software Developer Manuals, Volume 2 (from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm ) contains all the tables, rules, values and other information needed for the conversion of assembly into machine code (the bytes).

Be prepared to be daunted; it's not a simple process. Mostly, you use the instruction's name (mnemonic), current operating mode of the CPU and the instruction's operands to determine which addressing mode and then which opcode it is; then use multiple tables to determine how to encode the operands into the machine code.

Comment: Or locally, assemble then disassemble with `objdump -drwC`, with machine-code hexdump all on the same line as the disassembled instruction.  Count the bytes or look at address differences.